# After each reboot, speakers have volume 0

Tags: systemd, alsa, pulseaudio

For some reason my audio volume keeps being reduced to zero when I reboot.

I am able to fix this temporarily like so:

```
rm ~/.config/pulse/*
```

If I reboot, the volume functions normally.
Rebooting again resets it to zero again.

How do I get to the bottom of what is causing this?

I'm running Arch with Gnome 3 and pulseaudio.

Comment: I did "systemctl is-enabled" for both of those services and got "Failed to get unit file state for alsa-store.service: No such file or directory".

Comment: While the interconnections between pulse, alsa and systemd are still foggy to me, it looks like your suggestion fixed it. If you want to combine you comments into an answer I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `systemd` unit files `alsa-store.service` and `alsa-restore.service` which are responsible for saving volume settings before shutdown/reboot and respectively restoring those settings at start-up. They're part of `alsa-utils`. They are both "static" services (they're controlled automatically) so all you have to do is install `alsa-utils`:

```
pacman -S alsa-utils
```

and set volume level. Sound settings should then be preserved across reboots.